# Trying to chain linq queries, but not succeding

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have this problem where I have a "phrase" made of symbols and I was trying to "decode" the phrase into English. So I have a big list of English words, and I'm trying to write a linq query that will select tuples of words that match the symbols. here's what I'm trying:

```
public void Method()
{
     //here, based on the cryptic phrase, I gather English words
     //that have 7, 5, 4 and 2 letters in which all letters are distinct from one another
     var words7 = from word in Properties.Resources.Words
         where word.Length == 7 && allLettersAreDistinct(word)
         select word;
     var words5 = from word in Properties.Resources.Words
         where word.Length == 5 && allLettersAreDistinct(word)
         select word;
     var words4 = from word in Properties.Resources.Words
         where word.Length == 4 && allLettersAreDistinct(word)
         select word;
     var words2 = from word in Properties.Resources.Words
         where word.Length == 2 && allLettersAreDistinct(word)
         select word;

     //So this is where I try to make a query that select groups of words
     //that match the symbols in their positions in their locations
     //in the cryptic phrase words
     var level4Collection = from word7 in words7 select
         from word5 in words5 select
              from word4 in words4 select
                  from word2 in words2
                      where word5[1] == word7[0] &&
                      word5[3] == word7[5] &&
                      word4[1] == word5[0] &&
                      word4[2] == word7[2] &&
                      word2[0] == word7[1]
                      select
                      new Tuple<string, string, string, string>(word7, word4, word2, word5);
```

As a result of the above query I get an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>>>`

But linq is a complicated subject and my query clearly doesn't work as intended, let me explain:

Let me call the `Tuple<string, string, string, string>` objects *level 0 objects* and so forth

`IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>` is `IEnumerable<level 0>` and also *level 1 object*

`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>>` is `IEnumerable<level 1>` and also *level 2 object*

`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>>>` is `IEnumerable<level 2>` and also *level 3 object*

and finally 
`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, string, string>>>>>` is `IEnumerable<level 3>`

as I run the code, iterating through the many levels, I find that most `IEnumerable<level 0>` objects are empty. How can this be? If I requested a number of words that fit into specific criteria, then if there are no words that fit the criteria to form the `Tuple`, neither should be the `IEnumerables` of those empty `IEnumerables`. This is how I understand linq. Which is, of course, wrong.

What can I do to achieve the expected result and get the tuples of words that fit the criteria?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: What if you remove all the `select` keywords from the `level4Collection` query except the last one that projects a tuple?

Comment: @IvanStoev Why didn't tou turn that into an answer yet? It works, Just make it into an answer so I can approve it and this questions can get out of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

@IvanStoev says:

> remove all the select keywords from the level4Collection query except the last one that projects a tuple